# Rename a file to parent directory's name in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I have to deal with a large number of files nested inside of directories (one file per directory), resembling something like this:

```
fred/result.txt
john/result.txt
mary/result.txt
...
```

I am currently using the following command to process each of those files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c \"cd '{}' && processResult result.txt\" \;
```

I am looking for something I can add into the end of this command that will change the filenames to `fred.txt`, etc. and then later move the file into the parent directory to eliminate the extra layer of directories.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Backslash in filename is not allowed. Your best bet would be to use an underscore or some other special character. It's fairly easy to script , from what i see

Comment: @Serg Sorry, I meant renaming to 'fred.txt' still within the 'fred' folder - I'll edit the question to make that part clearer.

Comment: OK. So let me understand this correctly. We have for example `/home/user/some_tests/fred/results.txt` . You want that to become `/home/user/some_tests/fred.txt` .  Correcto ?

Comment: @Serg Yes, though at this stage going from `/home/user/some_tests/fred/results.txt` to `/home/user/some_tests/fred/fred.txt` would be acceptable

Comment: OK. ANy preference in scripting language ? Will post later. I am in class atm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the classical approach : `find`  with `while read`  combo:

Demo:

```
$ ls *
fred:
results.txt

jane:
results.txt

john:
results.txt

$> find . -type f -name "results.txt" -printf "/%P\n" | while read FILE ; do DIR=$(dirname "$FILE" );\                            
>  mv ."$FILE" ."$DIR""$DIR".txt;done                                                                                             
$> ls
fred/  jane/  john/
$> ls *
fred:
fred.txt

jane:
jane.txt

john:
john.txt
```

Use `echo` before using `mv` to test the line with your files.

**Minor improvement**

We can embed the call to `bash` into exec , with parameter expansion (specifically prefix removal). Basically it's embedding a script into exec call.

```
$> find "$PWD" -type f -name "results.txt" -exec bash -c ' DIR=$( dirname "{}"  ); echo "{}" "$DIR"/"${DIR##*/}".txt  ' \;                
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/fred/results.txt /home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/fred/fred.txt
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/jane/results.txt /home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/jane/jane.txt
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/john/results.txt /home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/john/john.txt
```

To make the command general, (working for any file, not just `results.txt`) just remove `-name "results.txt"` part. Also see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/901209/295286) for alternative Python solution to this.

Answer (score 8):

The small python script below will do exactly as you describe; it will:

- rename any file in given directory, named `results.txt`, according to its superior directory
- move it one (directory) level up
- delete the (now empty) directory where the file initially was located

***The result:***

This:

```
directory
|
├── fred
│   └── results.txt
├── john
│   └── results.txt
└── mary
    └── results.txt
```

will become:

```
directory
|
├── fred.txt
│   
├── john.txt
│ 
└── mary.txt
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for file in files:
        if file == "results.txt":
            spl = root.split("/"); newname = spl[-1]; sup = ("/").join(spl[:-1])
            shutil.move(root+"/"+file, sup+"/"+newname+".txt"); shutil.rmtree(root)
```

#### To use

- Copy the code below into an empty file, save it as `move_rename.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/move_rename.py <directory_to_reorganize>
  ```

#### Note

as always, first test it on a small sample

Answer (score 7):

I think this is legit (using the perl-based `rename` command)

```
find dir -name 'results.txt' -exec rename -nv -- 's|/(.*)/(.*)$|/$1/$1.txt|' {} +
```

e.g. given

```
$ tree dir
dir
├── fred
│   └── results.txt
├── john
│   └── results.txt
└── mary
    └── results.txt

3 directories, 3 files
```

then

```
$ find dir -name 'results.txt' -exec rename -v -- 's|/(.*)/(.*)$|/$1/$1.txt|' {} +
dir/fred/results.txt renamed as dir/fred/fred.txt
dir/john/results.txt renamed as dir/john/john.txt
dir/mary/results.txt renamed as dir/mary/mary.txt
```

resulting in

```
$ tree dir
dir
├── fred
│   └── fred.txt
├── john
│   └── john.txt
└── mary
    └── mary.txt

3 directories, 3 files
```

---

If you only need to go 1 level below `dir`, you may be able to simply do

```
rename -vn -- 's|/(.*)/(.*)$|/$1/$1.txt|' dir/*/results.txt
```

*As always, the `-n` option is left in for testing purposes*

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple files in folders with the same extensions, some of the above commands will overwrite all but one, renaming all files with the same name.

```
folder1/file1.txt file2.txt --> folder1/folder1.txt
```

To avoid this, you can use this command or equivalent:

```
for f in */*.txt ;do fp=$(dirname "$f"); fl=$(basename "$f"); mv "$fp/$fl" "$fp/$fp"_"$fl"; done
```

By keeping the full filename $fl rather than just the extension, you preserve all the files.

```
folder1/file1.txt file2.txt --> folder1/folder1_file1.txt folder1_file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it through find seems overly complicated. Why not use a simple for loop?

```
for folder in *; do
    (cd "$folder" && processResult result.txt)  # This replaces your previous find(1)
    mv "$folder/result.txt" "${folder}.txt"
    rmdir "$folder"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a trick with rsync + a for loop

```
mkdir renamed # here we will transfer the renamed files

for dir in ./*/ ; do echo rsync -Pavzh $dir"*.txt" ./renamed/$(basename $dir )".txt" ; done | bash 

rm -r ./renamed/result.txt # only error due to having renamed included in the loop above
```