# Rename files of the same name in multiple subdirectories

Tags: command-line, directory, batch-rename

I have multiple directories with unique identifying names. Within each of these are further identicle subdirectories generated by an automated analysis software. Within one of these subdirectories is a file I want to pick out and move to a unique dir, naming them after their respective parent directory.

For example:

Directories = A001 A002 A003 A004

Subdirectories = A001/files A002/files A003/files A004/files

Identical file name in each subdirectory = A001/files/aseg.mgz A002/files/aseg.mgz etc etc

Unique new directory = collated_aseg

I want to move all the aseg.mgz files into the collated_aseg dir and rename them so they are identifiable as coming from the original parent directory: e.g. A001_aseg.mgz (or equivalent).

I have looked at similar issues ([Rename a file to parent directory's name in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746860/rename-a-file-to-parent-directorys-name-in-terminal)) - however, these have only one layer of directory, whereas my issue has two. I was wondering whether this could be easily done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the intermediate directory name is apparently constant, it should be straightforward with a shell loop:

```
for d in A???; do echo cp "$d/files/aseg.mgz" "collated_aseg/$d.mgz"; done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it's doing the right thing. The `collated_aseg` directory must already exist. Replace `cp` with `mv` if you really want to rename (move) rather than copy.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very much a beginner and hadn't gotten around to understanding the use of loops.