# Rename files and move to parent directory and delete empty subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory, rename

```
ls */*/*
```

The output of the above command is shown below:

```
HP14_107_Ch/10785/outs:
metric_summ.csv

HP15_746_Ad/10746/outs: 
metric_summ.csv

HP16_317_TD/10787/outs:
metric_summ.csv
```

I want to rename all the csv files with their corresponding parent directory name and remove the sub-folders.

I want the output like this:

```
ls *

HP14_107_Ch:
HP14_107_Ch.csv

HP15_746_Ad: 
HP15_746_Ad.csv

HP16_317_TD:
HP16_317_TD.csv
```

I tried to follow this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746860/rename-a-file-to-parent-directorys-name-in-terminal) but it is not working.

Comment: "*it is not working*" is too vague to offer useful advice. Show us real input and output of what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, what command you tried?